# Bulk insert with returning IDs performance

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I've got a table which I want to insert around **1000 items each query**, and get their PK after creation, for later use as FK for other tables.

I've tried inserting them using [returning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-insert.html) syntax in postgresql.
but it takes around **10 sec** to insert

`INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (a1,a2,a3)....(a(n-2),a(n-1),a(n)) returning id;`

By removing `RETURNING` I get much better performance **~50ms.**

I think that if I can get an atomic operation to get the first id and insert the rows at the same time I could get better performance by removing the `RETURNING`.
but don't understand if that is possible.

Comment: In general `RETURNING` an ID does not slow down significantly an insert. Can you show a reproducible case?

Comment: @DanielVérité it seems that I get slower performance from another query and not from inserting.

Comment: @shevski Could you clarify? Does this mean that you eventually found equal performance with and without `RETURNING`?

Comment: @CharlBotha Well this is an old post, But I remember that I got similar performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate id using the nextval
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createsequence.html

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_val AS(
    VALUES(nextval('table_name_id_seq'),a1,a2,a3), 
        (nextval('table_name_id_seq'),a1,a2,a3) 
);
INSERT INTO table_name (id, col1, col2, col3)(
    SELECT column1,column2,column3,column4 
    FROM temp_val
);
SELECT column1 FROM temp_val;
```

Comment: @shevski yes it is: the nextval() result won't be used by other concurrent sessions.